# How to capture post method request in access log file?

Tags: tomcat, jboss, logfile

I am enabling the access log in jboss Server by uncommenting the below code in server.xml file

```
       <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
        prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".log"
        pattern="common" directory="${jboss.server.home.dir}/log" 
        resolveHosts="false" />
```

Access logs are creating on the daily basis.
I am able to see get method request in access log file but not able to see post method request. How can I capture the details of post method request in server access log file in jboss.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `pattern` as `common` which is equivalents to `'%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b`.

There is another pattern attribute `%m` --> for Request method (GET, POST, etc.) add that to your pattern e.g.

```
   <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
    prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".log"
    pattern="'%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b %m" directory="${jboss.server.home.dir}/log" 
    resolveHosts="false" />
```

More details are available here: [**Tomcat Access Valves**](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve/Introduction).

Hope this helps!!